# Cant set the tab background dynamically by using tabBackground in code

Tags: java, android, android-tablayout

Hi friends please help me out i want to make layouts like first two screens but i am getting layouts like 3,4 screens i had made using the selector.here in the xml i used tabBackground by called selector drawable in it if i can able get the tabBackground in the java code then i can able set it by using the position but i cant able found that please help me out guys

[image: this is the first screen i want to be like that]

[image: When i get the next tab it looks like this]
[image: But they are coming like this]

[image: This is the another selected tab]

Here is my layout code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/icon_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_bg"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_background"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/transparent"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My Selector code

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bg_redcolor" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/toolbar_bg"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Yes i found the solution

Comment: Can you talk about it?